# Short Summary on Review Page

Tags: review, product-view, ratings

In catalog/product/view.phtml I have:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true)?>
```

Which shows the summary_short.phtml version of the reviews, however, when I then click to go to the reviews the catalog/product/view.phtml is still used, so the same parameters will be used for the reviews summary, however it shows the rating/detailed.phtml version.

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1):

So what actually happens is that the layout handle `review_product_list` which also includes the normal catalog view but with a different main block type:

```
<block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

Now this block has a different function `getReviewsSummaryHtml` which will use different blocks to display the reviews and that is why you are getting different review templates for the two pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guy i read your problem thoroughly & have implemented.

`product/view.phtml` is used in  both cases but block types are different.

**Product Page**: When you are on product page this method

Layout file: `catalog.xml`

Layout handle used: `catalog_product_view`

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true) ?>
```

Shows the link  of review that goes to review detail page.

**Review Detail Page**

Layout file: `review.xml`

Layout handle: `review_product_list`

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)
```

shows the link  of review that goes to review form same page.